# Ajax not working in header file of frontend

Tags: magento-1.9

```
<form name="frmExotel" id="frmExotel" method="post" action="" >
    <input type="text" name="mobile_no" id="mobile_no" value="" />
    <button type="submit" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Submit')) ?>" name="sbmt" id="sbmt" onclick="return chk_validation()"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Submit') ?></span></span></button>
</form>
 <script>
   function chk_validation()
   {
            var mobile_no = jQuery("#mobile_no");

            jQuery.ajax({      
                type: "POST",
                data: 'mobile_no=' + mobile_no,
                dataType: 'JSON',
                url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('ajaxlogin/index/save'); ?>",
                success:function(response){                       
                    if (response){ alert("success");
                      jQuery('#result').html(response.result);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
```

IndexController.php

```
   class Exotel_AjaxLogin_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
   {    

  public function saveAction()
  { 

   $result = $this->getRequest()->getParam('mobile_no');
   $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));
  }
}
```

I am getting redirected to homepage only. I think I am missing something in config.xml file.

Comment: You are missing form key.

Comment: @PrasantaHatui - How to add form key?

Comment: just change button type to "button" from "submit"

Comment: @Piyush - thanks, its working now . But now issue is that I am not getting the success response in phtml file.

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
<form name="frmExotel" id="frmExotel" method="post" action="" >
  <input name="form_key" type="hidden" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" id="form_key" />
  <input type="text" name="mobile_no" id="mobile_no" value="" />
  <button type="submit" title="Submit" class="button">Submit</button> 
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var reqForm = new VarienForm('frmExotel', true);
//]]>
</script> 
<script>
jQuery('#frmExotel').submit(function(e){

  if (reqForm.validator && reqForm.validator.validate())   
   {

        var mobile_no = jQuery("#mobile_no").val();
        var form_key = jQuery("#form_key").val();
        var postData = {"form_key":form_key,"mobile_no":mobile_no};

        jQuery.ajax({      
            type: "POST",
            data: postData,
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('ajaxlogin/index/save'); ?>",
            success:function(response){                       
                if (response){ alert("success");
                  //jQuery('#result').html(response.result);
                }
            }
        });


   }
});   
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing data in wrong format. Use below code.

```
function chk_validation()
{
    var mobile_no = jQuery("#mobile_no");

    jQuery.ajax({      
        type: "POST",
        data: { mobile_no: mobile_no },
        dataType: 'JSON',
        url: "<?php echo $this->getUrl('ajaxlogin/index/save'); ?>",
        success:function(response){                       
            if (response){ alert("success");
              jQuery('#result').html(response.result);
            }
        }
    });
}
```